# Result of '\ref' for external processing

Tags: automation

In my thesis I have a few listings and I also want to provide them online because copying the listings from the PDF output is a bit cumbersome (scattered around multiple pages, line numbering is also copied,...). In the PDF it looks like[image]

which I get from

```
\lstinputlisting[label={lst:ex1},caption={R code for Example~\ref{ex:intro}},frame=single]{../R/Example1/PCAIntro.r}
```

Now I want to write a PHP script which provides the file `PCAIntro.r` online and I want to refer to "Example 2.1.0.1" there. So my question is:

How do I get the result `2.1.0.1` of `\ref{ex:intro}` to a separate file for further processing?

Comment: have you tried looking in the `.aux` file...?

Comment: @cmhughes I have always ignored the many files like `aux`, `bbl`, `blg`, `idx`, `ilg`, `lof`, `log`, `log`, `out`. I have to learn about `.aux`-files first. It looks promising. Thanks. But is there also a `tex` command to write a specific `\ref` to some file?

Comment: looks like you got a solution, nice work! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the `.aux` file. The following PHP code solves my problem using regular expressions:

```
<?php
$contents=file_get_contents("Filename.aux", "r");
$label="ex:intro";
$pattern="/(?:newlabel{".$label."}{{)([.[:alnum:]]*?)}/";
preg_match($pattern,$contents,$match);
echo $match[1];//contains "2.1.0.1"
?>
```

Simply adjust "Filename.aux" and "$label" appropriately.